# How to create the 'paper mache' texture used along with the Acrylic Accent by Microsoft?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-composition-api

I would like to generate the 'paper mache' texture that MS is using in its own apps, like Groove and Movie.

I already know how to create the transparent background, using CreateHostBackdropBrush() etc.

I only want to know if someone have some idea on the particular texture used, maybe using some Composition effect?

Here is an example:

[image]

Any idea?

I love it!

Comment: Would it be some sort of repeating png/bmp with lots of alpha?

Comment: @Neil   I also thought that, but I think there is some Composition or Win2D Effect already defined...

Comment: They are actually using an image saved in Assets.